# Implementing thread in a nested loop using C++

Tags: c++

Background info:

I am trying to make some complex mathematical series calculations, and these calculations end up with either extremely big numbers, exceeding 1000 digits, or numbers that are too precise, having more than 1000 decimal digits. In order to handle mathematical operations between such numbers, I made my own string functions that take 2 numbers as parameter and make the mathematical operations on them digit by digit. Let me provide you some information regarding those functions that I made and their return types, because I think that you will have to understand my code well in order to decide whether or not implementing threads is possible in my case.

string product(string sx, string sy) -> returns product of sx and sy

string smaller_number(string sx, string sy) -> returns the smaller of the two numbers. If the 2 numbers are mathematically equal, the functions returns "EQUAL"

Necessary info:

In my code, I'm basically trying to find the square root of 5; I do this by declaring [string root = "2.";]. And then, my program goes into a nested loop.
The outer loop adds 1 zero at the end of 'root' each turn and its (outer loop's) index corresponds to the index of the decimal digit, and each inner loop is used to increment the last digit of 'root' until (root^2) is equal to 5 or exceeds 5.
Also, in my code, the number that will be square rooted is called 'sx', and it's a string.

The reason that I can't figure out how to implement threads on my own is that pretty much everything in my code needs information from something that is above. Here is my code:

```
    for(int k = 1; k <= precision; k++)// outer loop
    {
        root = root + "0";

        if(sx_is_decimal) // Don't mind this scope
        {
            if(smaller_number(product(root, root), sx) == "EQUAL")
            {
                return root;
            }
        }

        for(int i = 1; smaller_number(sx, product(root, root)) != sx; i++)// inner loop
        {
            root.back() = i + '0';
        }
        root.back() = (int)root.back() - 1; // Un-does the last execution of the inner loop
        cout << endl << "Digit " << k << " done";
    }
```

I will also appreciate it if you can suggest some optimizations here. I tried my very best and spent hours in order to optimize my 'product' and 'smaller_number' functions. Also the use of my string functions is a must, I can't use standard integral-types.

Comment: 1) Not all problems are parallelizable. 2) If this is the question about the performance only, [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is better place for such a question.

Comment: If the code inside the loop depends on the previous loops, then it can't really be turned into threaded code easily or at all. Threads and parallelism is good only if the data each thread works on is independent of the data the other threads work on.

Comment: The easy way to ensure no other thread modifies data from under you is to not let threads access each other's data. You *copy in* the inputs to your threaded functions

Comment: Your code is not an [MCVE]

Comment: Ok, thank you all, I guess this code can't be parallelized after all. Should the question be removed or kept intact?@BasileStarynkevitch I made it short and easy enough to read and comprehend, I think, no?